# Binding Text to gridview headers

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I have a grid in which i wanted to bind header columns of grid dynamically.

For that i made grid as:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSearch" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjects1" runat="server"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
         <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjects2" runat="server"  />
        </HeaderTemplate> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjects3" runat="server"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjects4" runat="server"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I wanted to bind text to this header check boxes.

Hence My first attemt was to bind text to it on `RowDataBound` event.

I made it as:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
For i As Integer = 0 To ds1.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
CType(e.Row.FindControl("chkSubjects'" & i + 1 & "'"), CheckBox).Text = DirectCast(ds1.Tables(0).Columns(i), System.Data.DataColumn).ColumnName
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = DirectCast(ds1.Tables(0).Columns(i), System.Data.DataColumn).ColumnName
Next
End If
```

But it was giving me error on `CType(e.Row.FindControl("chkSubjects'" & i + 1 & "'"), CheckBox).Text` as Object Referace, and when i made quickwatch it was giving its value as `Referance object has value of nothing`

I written same code with BindGrd function calling it onload as:

```
  Private Sub BindGrd()
            For i As Integer = 0 To ds1.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                CType(gvSearch.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSubjects'" & i + 1 & "'"), CheckBox).Text = DirectCast(ds1.Tables(0).Columns(i), System.Data.DataColumn).ColumnName
            Next
        End Sub
```

Here i added `HeaderRow` as shown above, but this code was also giving same error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  binding the data source just below try to rename the columns like

```
gv.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Text = ds.tables(1).columns(0).columnName;
gv.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Text = ds.tables(1).columns(1).columnName;
```

also handle the rows count value > 0

some thing like above